# why my upvote button only works for the first post?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I follow the instruction in  [tangowithdjango](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html) to add a 'like' button into my forum app.

the html file  and javascript:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#upvote").click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid = $(this).attr("data-r-id");
    $.get('/upvote/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
              
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<a id="upvote" data-r-id="{{r.id}}" class="label-info label pull-right">赞<div id="like_count">{{r.upvotes}}</div></a>
```

views.py

```
def upvote(request):
    post_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
    votes = 0
    if post_id:
        p = post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        if p :
            votes = p.upvotes + 1
            p.upvotes = votes
            p.save()
    return HttpResponse(votes)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^upvote/$', 'upvote', name='upvote'),
)
```

when click the  #upvote button ,the #like_count increase by one . However , it works just for the first post. If I click the rest of posts , I get no response at all.

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons on same page? That means you using same id parameter for all ur buttons. The id is an ID for a html element, it has to be unique on a given html document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to give `upvote` as class  not as id because id refers an unique element in your document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".upvote").click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid = $(this).attr("data-r-id");
    $.get('/upvote/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               $('#like-count-' + postid).html(data);

    });
  });
});
```

and your html should look like,

```
<a data-r-id="{{r.id}}" class="label-info label pull-right upvote">赞<div id="like-count-{{r.id}}">{{r.upvotes}}</div></a>
```

Comment: thank you !  It really helps me a lot. But when I click the second button , the first `like_count`  increased by one . then I tried to give `like_count` as class. this time both of two `like_count`  increased...

Comment: @ming now it should be unique. Check my updated post.

Comment: Thank you ! it is unique now !  really appreciate your help :)